# psycopg2.errors.SyntaxError: Syntax Error at end of input

Tags: psycopg2

```
insert into l1.portal_files_download_dashboard_tracker_final(files_to_download, tax_id, site_code, health_plan, file_type, health_plan_lob, market, dlp_to_download, provider_reporting_option, tat_for_availibility, tat_for_innovaccer_download, tat_to_upload_files_sftp, signature_job_present, file_month, file_name, upload_date, download_status, upload_status) 
select distinct b.files_to_download, b.tax_id, b.site_code, b.health_plan, b.file_type, b.health_plan_lob, b.market, b.dlp_to_download, b.provider_reporting_option, b.tat_for_availibility, b.tat_for_innovaccer_download, b.tat_to_upload_sftp, b.signature_job_present, initcap(to_char(now(), 'mon-yyyy')) as file_month, a.file_name, a.upload_date as upload_date, '' as download_status, '' as upload_status from l1.portal_downloaded_files a right join l1.dashboard_files_tracker_csv b on lower(split_part(a.file_name,'.',1)) like '%' || lower(split_part(b.files_to_download,'.',1)) || '%' where tat_for_availibility ilike '%9th of the Month%';
```

Facing Error in end of query. Running in Python Script using psycopg2. (Postgres)

using cur.execute(query).

Can someone tell me why I am facing error here

Comment: Your SQL join is not per the syntax, missing the like in 2nd part, correct it, then it will work.

Answer (score 0):

The || is used for string concatenation in postgresql. You should use the OR in your join condition, also misplaced the `like`.
Below is the corrected query,

`insert into l1.portal_files_download_dashboard_tracker_final(files_to_download, tax_id, site_code, health_plan, file_type, health_plan_lob, market, dlp_to_download,  provider_reporting_option, tat_for_availibility, tat_for_innovaccer_download,  tat_to_upload_files_sftp, signature_job_present, file_month, file_name, upload_date, download_status, upload_status)  select distinct b.files_to_download, b.tax_id, b.site_code, b.health_plan, b.file_type, b.health_plan_lob, b.market, b.dlp_to_download,  b.provider_reporting_option, b.tat_for_availibility, b.tat_for_innovaccer_download, b.tat_to_upload_sftp, b.signature_job_present,  initcap(to_char(now(), 'mon-yyyy')) as file_month,  a.file_name, a.upload_date as upload_date, '' as download_status, '' as upload_status  from l1.portal_downloaded_files a right join l1.dashboard_files_tracker_csv b  on lower(split_part(a.file_name,'.',1)) like '%' OR lower(split_part(b.files_to_download,'.',1)) like '%' where tat_for_availibility ilike '%9th of the Month%';`